# How to write unit tests for offchain workers?

Tags: offchain-worker, unit-tests

Pallets can have unit tests with a mock runtime where extrinsics are tested against multiple cases.

However it's not obvious how to do the same for offchain workers.

How can I write unit tests for offchain workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/merkle-mountain-range/src/tests.rs#L36-L40) to register the offchain ext.

It's a really good example. Check the whole `tests.rs`.